# Problems on generating Connection Key for integration app with Quick Books Online Edition

Tags: quickbooks

I am having problems generating a QBOE connection key, when i follow the wizard to generate the connection key, the text box that sould have generated the key is simply blank.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Post a screenshot of your application registration screen, and the URLs you're visiting to establish the connection.

You most likely have something mis-configured with your application registration, but you'll need to show us/tell us what you've done so far if you expect to get any useful answers.